# Create map plot with discrete colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have just started to use ggplot2 and have created a map overlaid with data represented by a continuous color map. The data runs from 0.205 to 0.756. However, I would like to plot the data with 'n' discrete colors, and with the mid point at 0.5.

I have modified the relevant part of my code to the following:

```
...
df %>% # dataframe
mutate(value_cut = cut_interval(value, n = 6)) %>%
ggplot() -> gg

gg <- gg + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,
                            fill = value_cut), size = 0.25, color = NA)
gg <- gg + viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE,direction=-1)
...
print(gg)
```

which generates the following plot:
[image: map with discrete data levels]

It is almost there, but I would like to be able to specify an 'even' number of unique colors and have the mid-point set at 0.5. I have tried a number of different approaches but, usually end up with errors.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want full control over the intervals used to discretize your data, you might want to use the `cut` function from base R instead; see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut.

Comment: Thanks, this worked by setting breaks=c(0.2,0.35,0.5,0.65,0.8), which resulted in 4 discrete colors. More breaks increases the number of colors. Now all I need to be able to do is set my own colors - any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, take a look at ColorBrewer (http://colorbrewer2.org/) and then use `scale_fill_manual` to apply the vector you select.

Comment: I tried: gg <- gg + scale_colour_manual(values = cols), where cols <- c("yellow","gold","lightblue","royalblue"), but the colors did not show up. Instead the color scheme was the default c("red","green","blue","mauve") .

Comment: I think you want `scale_fill_manual`, which controls the fill colors, and not `scale_colour_manual`, which controls the colors of the borders.

Comment: Yes, my apology. This works fine. Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am including my answer in case it helps someone in future.

Following advice from `ulfelder`, I used R functions `cut()` and `scale_fill_manual()`, when the relevant code becomes

```
...
df %>%
  mutate(value_cut = cut(value, breaks=c(0.2,0.35,0.5,0.65,0.8))) %>%
  ggplot() -> gg

# Create the coloured map using the ggplot2 package
# color=NA omits demarcation lines between constituencies
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,
                            fill = value_cut),
                        size = 0.25, color = NA)
cols <- c("yellow","gold","lightblue","royalblue")
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
...
print(gg)
```

which generates the following plot:

[image]

as required.

More discrete colors can be readily achieved by increasing the number of `breaks` when calling the `cut()` function, and increasing the number of colors in the `cols` array.

Many thanks to `ulfelder` for the excellent and prompt advice.